# Resolve GIT merge conflicts in Tableau workbook TWB file

Tags: git, tableau-api, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

We are trying to set-up parallel development using git feature branches and faced an issue trying to resolve merge conflicts within tableau workbooks.

TWB files are actually XMLs of a complex structure, and in most cases, it is absolutely impossible to understand changes and merge conflicts just looking at the XML diffs, there are too many changed lines. For example, I only remove one worksheet from workbook and I get 4k lines added and 4,5k lines removed in git commit window. Diff is a total mess.

I would be grateful for some hints, tips, and tricks on how to set up Tableau git process that works well.

Comment: If the merging is as tricky as you say, it seems like it'd be wise to avoid working on the same files in parallel. Git's model, as you may know, by its distributed nature has no support for locking. Aside from working fast and rebasing often to avoid (too many) conflicts, as far as I know there is nothing out of the box that will solve this. There are third-party options if you really want locking. Gitolite for example has https://gitolite.com/gitolite/locking.html.

Comment: If it's a critical business requirement, contact Tableau directly for this. Their customer support, or your Tableau account/relationship manager will be able to get you much better help on this. After all they have developed the software and must be tracking such changes for  them.